# React react-jsonschema-form not re-rendering when schema changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

EDIT: Here is a simple fiddle that shows what is going on.  Clicking "Change" changes the state but does not update (re-render) the form:

https://jsfiddle.net/mbaranski/pt20o4w7/

I have the following form:

```
const FormComponent = ({create, token, cas, createUISchema}) => {

    console.log("Schema", cas)
    return (
        <Grid>
            <Row>
                <Col sm={12} md={4}>
                    <Form schema={cas}
                          uiSchema={createAuditUISchema}
                          onSubmit={(data) => {
                              create(token, data)
                          }}
                    />
                </Col>
            </Row>
        </Grid>
    )
}
```

I have a schema like this (initially):

```
export const formSchema = {
    "title": "Creat Form",
    "description": "Create something.",
    "type": "object",
    "required": [
        "itemId",
    ],
    "properties": {
        "itemId": {
            "type": "string",
            "title": "Item",
            "enum": ["1"],
            "enumNames": ["A"]
        },
    ...
```

Now, the form renders fine and I see a `select` element with one value in it (and the `console.log` shows the correct data)

My issue comes when I have an async change that updates `cas`. (I also see the `console.log` re-fire with the updated `enum` and `enumNames` values so I know the FormComponent is re-rendering).  The form does not re-render and display the new values.

I'm using redux, but we're simply re-rendering a component here.  I'm also using this lib in a number of places and this is the only issue I can't figure out.

Does `Form` not handle receiving new properties?  Is there something I need to do to make it update?  I haven't seen any documentation on this on the github page.

Here is the `mapStateToProps` method:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    const cas = Object.assign({}, createFormSchema, {})
    state.auth.dynamicItems.forEach((item) => {
            cas.properties.itemId.enumNames.push(item.name)
            cas.properties.itemId.enum.push(item.id)
        }
    )
    const stp = {
        token: state.auth.token,
        cas,
        createAuditUISchema,
    }
    return stp
}
```

Comment: There's probably not enough code here to answer this question. Are you mutating the schema in place? if so whatever `Form` is might not know it changed

Comment: I added my `mapStateToProps` and the first thing I do is `Object.assign` my object to a new `const` and push the array values on there, so I guess to answer your question no, I am not mutating in place, every time the state changes `cas` gets re-created